# Geo Nodes Branching, forking, splitting

Tags: geometry-nodes

I can instance a mesh onto a curve to make a cable with a plug at the end. I've placed an object at the other end of the cable to act as a junction where two cables would split off, forming a 'Y'.

Question; How would I place multiple curves to start out of the junction mesh at Surface (1)?

THanks

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the nodes you're using, *Point Instance* for example, are deprecated in newer versions of Blender. I'm using 3.2, so my setup will look very different from your current one, but the logic is largely the same so hopefully it won't be too hard to follow. Since you have two empties already placed where you want the new curves to go, I used a similar scene. The two empties are parented to the main socket body:

[image]

Here, I created two *Curve Line*s (<kbd>Shift+A</kbd> *> Curve Primitives > Curve Line*) inside the Geometry Nodes itself and gave them a simple circular profile to mimic plug pins, but of course, you could use objects from outside via an *Object Info* node. In this second example I'm bringing in an outside spiral object and instancing them on a *Curve Line* I created between the two empties. The *Resample* count then determines how many copies are placed on that line:

[image]

Comment: thank you, this is perfect, especially the extra step of more the 2.

Comment: @OthoapProto You're welcome. You might wanna accept it as a solution then.